# Windows phone Geolocator always notInitialized

Tags: c#, gps, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to mak my app check if location service (GPS) is enabled or not in the phone.

I found really a lot of links on google and every single one was talking about this code:

```
Geolocator geoLocator = new Geolocator();
if (geoLocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
{
   //in this case the status of the gps is "DISABLED"
}
```

Now, where is my problem? My problem is that **in any case** my status is always `notInitialized`.

I tried enabling the GPS. I tried disabling the GPS. Nothing, always `NotInitialized`.

The only difference is that if the GPS is turned off, when calling `await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync()`, it throws an error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
```

> Your App does not have permission to access location data. Make sure
>   you have defined ID_CAP_LOCATION in the application manifest and that
>   on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings >
>   Location.

**NOTE:**

I have ID_CAP_LOCATION, but the GPS is turned off, so I need to check if it is enabled or not but the code above isn't working. Why?

Comment: Is your gps is working fine with other location related apps??

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava unfortunatly yes. I just found that after like a minute of running the problem solves. but I don't get why in this app at the beginning the status is that one

Comment: Ok use that code inside `OnNaviagtedTo()` method.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava the problem is the following: I have a splashScreen page, a login page, a sync page and after this my menu page. only after that the menu page is loaded and after like 2-3 seconds, the location become ready

Comment: Happens to me also. My devices is updated to Windows 10 Mobile already, and this happens. My theory would be that the `Geolocator` API could have been deprecated in WIndows 10 mobile